# Google Map marker not working with geocoder in Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Geocoder to convert address to a coordinate which is added to a previous array of coordinates all of which I want to map on googleMaps. All values are being mapped except the ones I add in array using GeoCoder. Can anyone help ?

```
Following is my code : coordinatesArray is the array in which I push the new value computed from my code.

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = route.fullname;
    var latitude , longitude;
    geocoder.geocode({'address' : address}, function(results, status) {                                                 
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {    
            latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            alert("Name : " + address + " : " + latitude + " : "
                                + longitude);
            coordinatesArray.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude));
                    }});


function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom : 8,
            disableDefaultUI : true,
            center : coordinatesArray[0],
            mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),mapOptions);

        var mapPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
            path : coordinatesArray,
            geodesic : true,
            strokeColor : 'green',
            strokeOpacity : 1.0,
            strokeWeight : 2
        });
        mapPath.setMap(map);
    }
```

Any advice where I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Figured out that it is an asynchronous call. How can this be fixed ?

Comment: The code seems to me correct, I tried it with an address known to me and gave me the expected result. Are you sure that the place you indicated returns a geocode correct ?. In some cases it is not enough to check the `status`, you must also check what returned. Typically the return values is reported for example that in that location is not possible to geocode.

Comment: @scaisEdge The result I verified is correct as well. The issue I have figured is that as geocode is an asynchronous call the resulting coordinates arn't added to the array when the map is displayed. Do you know how to fix it ?

Comment: I make hundreds of geocode a day and I've never hit a problem of delayed response to such effects, strange.
In the event that this is actually the hypothesis why not enter the display (or the call to a display function) in the body of the function executed asynchronously? Basically if I understand it comes to adding a marker, so that once you get the results you show on the map.